# ChkTeX install not working on OSX 10.10.4

Tags: macos, latex, osx-yosemite

i tried to setup a latex linter in atom. The one I found was linter-chktex. For it to be working I have to install ChkTeX. So I have downloaded it [here](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/chktex/). But every time I'm trying to `make` i get the following error:
    FindErrs.c:39:10: fatal error: 'pcreposix.h' file not found

Can someone explain to me how to get it working?

EDIT: I fixed this error by giving the full path of pcreposix.h after locating it. `make` does work now and here is the log:

```
gcc -M -I. -I. -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -D__unix__ Utility.c > .Utility.d.tmp
sed 's,\(Utility\)\.o *:,\1.o .Utility.d : Makefile,g' .Utility.d.tmp > .Utility.d
rm -f .Utility.d.tmp 2>/dev/null
gcc -M -I. -I. -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -D__unix__ Resource.c > .Resource.d.tmp
sed 's,\(Resource\)\.o *:,\1.o .Resource.d : Makefile,g' .Resource.d.tmp > .Resource.d
rm -f .Resource.d.tmp 2>/dev/null
gcc -M -I. -I. -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -D__unix__ OpSys.c > .OpSys.d.tmp
sed 's,\(OpSys\)\.o *:,\1.o .OpSys.d : Makefile,g' .OpSys.d.tmp > .OpSys.d
rm -f .OpSys.d.tmp 2>/dev/null
gcc -M -I. -I. -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -D__unix__ FindErrs.c > .FindErrs.d.tmp
sed 's,\(FindErrs\)\.o *:,\1.o .FindErrs.d : Makefile,g' .FindErrs.d.tmp > .FindErrs.d
rm -f .FindErrs.d.tmp 2>/dev/null
gcc -M -I. -I. -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -D__unix__ ChkTeX.c > .ChkTeX.d.tmp
sed 's,\(ChkTeX\)\.o *:,\1.o .ChkTeX.d : Makefile,g' .ChkTeX.d.tmp > .ChkTeX.d
rm -f .ChkTeX.d.tmp 2>/dev/null
gcc -I. -I. -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -D__unix__ -g -O2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wall -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.37/include -c ChkTeX.c -o ChkTeX.o
gcc -I. -I. -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -D__unix__ -g -O2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wall -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.37/include -c FindErrs.c -o FindErrs.o
gcc -I. -I. -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -D__unix__ -g -O2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wall -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.37/include -c OpSys.c -o OpSys.o
gcc -I. -I. -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -D__unix__ -g -O2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wall -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.37/include -c Resource.c -o Resource.o
gcc -I. -I. -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -D__unix__ -g -O2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wall -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.37/include -c Utility.c -o Utility.o
gcc -L/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.37/lib -lpcreposix -lpcre -o chktex ChkTeX.o FindErrs.o OpSys.o Resource.o Utility.o -ltermcap
```

But as soon as I try to `sudo make install` this error appears:

```
no ChkTeX.tex
make: no: No such file or directory
make: *** [ChkTeX.dvi] Error 1
```

But the `ChkTeX.tex` is in the directory.

Comment: If anyone else stumbles here, I also fixed the problem by providing the include path to pcreposix.h. On my system, it was installed with `brew install pcre`. To find the path, run `brew list pcre`. To add it to the include path, set `CPATH`. E.g. in my case: `export CPATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre/8.45/include/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem.

Turns out `make` does not find the file `no` in your directory. `no` is the content of the `LATEX` variable in the Makefile, if `./configure` did not find a LaTeX distribution.

If you set the `LATEX` variable to the path of your `latex` executable, you can run `sudo make install` without a problem.

In my case (El Capitan) I had to put

```
LATEX=/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin/latex
```

on line 48 of the makefile, and thereby replace

```
LATEX=no
```

to make it work.